# No WiFi adapter found, intel 8265

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, 21.04

I just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my laptop and when I try to connect to my WiFi network in settings it says no WiFi adapter found. I tried the "additional drivers" section with no result. The laptop has the [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/94150/intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-8265.html) adapter by the way, which I thought would be supported by default... Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If in a previous update or current version wifi was working then probably you mess with software & update center, you should leave that repositories default or what you checked to uncheck them, run apt update; apt upgrade but make sure you connected to the internet while doing this, you can use USB or Bluetooth tethering. and restart pc for 1-2 times.

Comment: This is not helpful and is also false. I have exactly the same issue and didn't touch any repos, or settings, to arrive at the same problem. The hardware is loaded and usable, even connected to the internet through NetworkManager and netplan, but is still listed as no network adapter available in gnome settings.

Please only answer if you have helpful advice.